# qSort() doesn't work with own compare function

Tags: c++, qt, sorting, qt5, qsort

I want to use `qSort()` as follows.

I have a compare function called

```
bool CStreamSetup::compareNames(const QString &s1, const QString &s2)
{
    QString temp1 = s1.section("Stream", 1);
    temp1 = temp1.section('_', 0, 0);

    QString temp2 = s2.section("Stream", 1);
    temp2 = temp2.section('_', 0, 0);

    return (temp1.toInt() < temp2.toInt());
}
```

and a QStringList with 160 elements called `QStringList childKeys;`

When I call the QSort function as follows:

```
qSort(childKeys.begin(), childKeys.end(), compareNames);
```

the following errors appear.

```
'compareNames': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
'qSort': no matching overloaded function found
'void qSort(Container &)': expects 1 arguments - 3 provided
'void qSort(RandomAccessIterator, RandomAccessIterator)' expects 2 arguments - 3 provided
```

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Static function

The member function needs to be `static` if you want to use it as a comparator:

```
static bool compareNames(const QString &s1, const QString &s2);
```

#### Anonymous function (lambda)

Another way (C++11 and later) is to use lambdas:

```
qSort(childKeys.begin(), childKeys.end(), [this](const QString &s1, const QString &s2) {
    return compareNames(s1, s2);
});
```

#### STL function

Side note: according to the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtalgorithms-obsolete.html#qSort), `qSort` is obsolete and Qt recommends using `std::sort` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Comparator cannot be a method of class (method of class needs an object for which it is called). You can define `compareNames` as static function in `CStreamSetup` class:

```
class CStreamSetup {
  static bool CStreamSetup::compareNames(const QString &s1, const QString &s2);
  // ^^^
};
```

the definition of `compareNames` remains the same.

```
bool CStreamSetup::compareNames(const QString &s1, const QString &s2)
{
    QString temp1 = s1.section("Stream", 1);
    //...
}
```

or you can just define comparator as free function:

```
bool compareNames(const QString &s1, const QString &s2)
{
    QString temp1 = s1.section("Stream", 1);
    //...
}
```